# Customise looks plotly.js legends

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, svg, plotly

I have created an independent y-ax for every trace created. Sometimes there are to many traces/y axis.

I would like to have the legend buttons inside of an option list with same native functionality: click-toggles trace visibility. Ideally when hiding a trace by clicking its legend , its y-axis(tick values) would also be hidden.

Also it be nice that if all traces/y-axis are displayed -> set max width to the container holding the y-axis in order for the plot/graph area/domain to always take at least 70% of width (setting an overflow:scroll to the y-axis container)

[image]

I have gone through the docs but not fount what I need..

```
layout.showlegend = true/false -> hides/shows all the legend box
trace1.showlegend = true/false -> hides/shows one legend(for trace1) in the box
```

if i do:

```
trace1.visible= false -> I hide both the trace and legend for it
trace1.opacity= 0 ->hides the trace not the legend for it but alters the legend icon(if line+dot -> only line)
```

Which attribute is changed natively when toggeling the legend links in order to hide the trace but keep the legend button for it intact?

Need to know to implement the functionality through a multi select dropdown

Comment: Mind explaining why down vote so I can improve the question if really necessary???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution
use a form of dropdown element instead of playing with the limited legend box which display we set to false:

```
$scope.layout = {showlegend:false};
```

I Used  AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect as setters for the ng-models that hold the values for the alterable elements of the layout or trace objects of the graph.

For example when hiding first y-axis:

```
$scope.layout.yaxis.showticklabels = false;
```

On changes of the ng-models of the dropdowns I update the traces and layout attributes, for example setting an array of traces to visible in a loop:

```
$scope.trace[i].visible = false;
```

On changes -> update plotly draw...

My issue was that my original idea was to play with the already rendered svg while altering the graph objects.

The aproach I have now followed works very well and is easy to implement:

[image]

Comment: could you please share the code, which adds black right-border for axes?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem - could you please share your code or give a bit more details?

Answer (score 1):

An automatic y-overflow for legends has been added in the most recent release - it will automatically be toggled on when there are enough legend items to push the legend beyond the bottom of the plot.

Unfortunately, there are only a few ways to customize the appearance of legends at the moment - background color, border color, and fonts. Work is being done to improve the legend customization and the ability to have dropdowns within it, but because of limitations when working with mixed svg and html, it won't be fully implemented for some time still - there are higher priorities for plotly.js.

The docs have a [few examples](https://plot.ly/javascript/high-dimension-data/) that may be helpful for your use case with an option select.

Comment: Thx for your comment, my original approach was simply not right